# watchOS Error: Unknown property in Interface description for controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchos-2

I added a WKInterfacePicker to the storyboard and connected it to an IBOutlet in the interface controller. While running the application, it shows an error message in the console:

> Unknown property in Interface description ('watchPicker') for controller

Code:

```
@interface InterfaceController()
{
    __unsafe_unretained IBOutlet WKInterfacePicker *watchPicker;
}
@end
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create IBOutlet as property for **WKInterfacePicker**, you will not get message.

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfacePicker *sd;
```

Comment: That's disappointing. I wish I can use instance variables instead of properties.