# Swift WatchOS Error: Unknown property in Interface description ('image') for controller

Tags: swift, watchkit

I get this error on watchOS

"*Unknown property in Interface description ('image') for controller*"

The declaration looks like this:

```
class AnimationButton: WKInterfaceButton {
   @IBOutlet var image:WKInterfaceImage?
   ...
```

Is it not possible to have IBOutlets in custom WatchKit classes on WatchOS?

A fix in Objective-c might be to declare a property, but how does that translate to swift? 
[Objective-C error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715309/watchos-error-unknown-property-in-interface-description-for-controller)

Edit: It looks like interface builder doesn't allow the declaration of outlets via dragging to custom classes

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to have custom WatchKit classes.

> Do not subclass or create instances of this class, or any of its subclasses, yourself.

[WKInterfaceObject - Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfaceobject)